# Is it possible to loop on two datagrid in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview

For example code:

```
For Each r As DataGridViewRow In datagrid1 and datagrid2
next
```

I just need to loop on two data grid view at once to print on crystal report

Comment: Do you have the same number of rows in the two grids? Do you have the same number of columns with the same datatype in the same order?

Comment: No sir. They have different sets of data via select comming from my mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand what each of the different loops is and is not.  You'd see that your example is nonsensical in that case but there are options.

Firstly, a loop is a code construct that enables you to execute a section of code multiple times.  That's true of all loops.  The difference is how the loop decides when to stop looping.

A `For Each` loop will execute the section of code once for each item in an enumerable list, providing access to the current item via the loop control variable.  You can, for instance, loop over the `Rows` collection of a `DataGridView`, accessing the current row each time.

If you want to process two grids, you need to first be clear about what that means, which you have not done here.  Is the intention to process pairs of rows together, i.e. one from each grid at corresponding indexes, or process each row individually, regardless of the source?  If it's the former, you would use a `For` lop and then index both `Rows` collections by the loop counter, e.g.

```
For i = 0 To grid1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row1 = grid1.Rows(i)
    Dim row2 = grid2.Rows(i)

    '...
Next
```

If it's the latter then you need to create a single list of items from both grids.  You can do that as part of the `For Each` statement but it is nothing to do with the loop, e.g.

```
For Each row In grid1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().Concat(grid2.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)())
    '...
Next
```

Comment: Ill try your code sir and ill update on this thread. Thank you and God bless sir.

Answer (score 0):

i have successfully looped on two datagrid at once by using the code below provided by Sir.jmcilhinney.

```
  For i = 0 To vmc.dgReservation.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim r = vmc.dgReservation.Rows(i)
        Dim r2 = vmc.dgBilling.Rows(i)
        Dim r3 = vmc.dgPayment.Rows(i)

        dt.Rows.Add(r.Cells("Check In").Value, _
          r.Cells("Check Out").Value, _
          r.Cells("Room No.").Value, _
          r.Cells("Nights").Value, _
          r.Cells("Rate").Value, _
          r2.Cells("Total Room Fee").Value, _
          r2.Cells("Other Charges Total").Value, _
          r3.Cells("Payment Method").Value, _
          r3.Cells("Total Amt. Due").Value)

    Next
```